# Exe for my python script does not run because it does not recognize the module PIL

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

I have completed a python project and want to make an exe for easy acces. After creating said exe, I tried to run it but an error states "no module named 'PIL'". Everything works perfect when executing script from the interpreter.

I have tried:

- Updating PIL and Image
- Changing `PIL` to `pil` as suggested in another question (does not recognize module)
- Changing `import PIL` to `import Image` (also not recognized)

If more details are needed I shall provide them.

Comment: I had two smal errors when runing the code that didnt seam to crash anything. It was something about "Bitmaps" or so I think. There was something wrong when trying to create the exe. But I upgraded pyinstaller and then it worked out fine for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to include the path of the libraries in your setup. Example (from [docs](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/spec-files.html)):

```
block_cipher = None
a = Analysis(['minimal.py'],
     pathex=['/Developer/PItests/minimal'],
     binaries=None,
     datas=None,
     hiddenimports=[],
     hookspath=None,
     runtime_hooks=None,
     excludes=None,
     cipher=block_cipher)
```

You need to include the pathes to the modules in the `pathex` parameter. If this still does not solve your issue, then the pyinstaller is not recognizing your import. You can set it explicitly in the `hiddenimports` parameter.